# Call function in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Hi guys i need to call this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* var bcf_settings = { buttonText:'Contact Us', buttonTop:'30%', language:'en_US' }; // Better Contact Form Settings */
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "http://bettercontactform.com/contact/media/0/5/058aba0d4d2a6e62dff91304ae52fde4746db476.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, "script", "bcf-render"));
</script>
```

with this button:

```
 <a href="" class="button-big">Click</a>
```

How can i do? thanks.

Comment: You cannot. Its an anonymous function it runs as soon as page gets ready/document starts to load in broswer.

Comment: no, this script doesnt' run when the page starts to load, i don't even see it the one way for run it i think it's calling it with a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is currently an IIFE (Immediately invoked function expression). If you want to call it from a button-click, or anywhere else, you'll need to store a reference to it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* var bcf_settings = { buttonText:'Contact Us', buttonTop:'30%', language:'en_US' }; // Better Contact Form Settings */
    var namedFunction = (function a (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "http://bettercontactform.com/contact/media/0/5/058aba0d4d2a6e62dff91304ae52fde4746db476.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        return a;
        }(document, "script", "bcf-render"));
</script>
```

And then you can call the function from a jQuery click event on your button (since you have tagged as jQuery):

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.button-big').click(function () {
            namedFunction(document, "script", "bcf-render");
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

EDIT: After taking a quick look at [bettercontactform.com](http://bettercontactform.com/), it looks like it's looking for a bettercontactform.com link with id and rel properties of `bcf_trigger`

Try adding the following to your link (be sure to keep the rest of your code the same, ignoring my previous suggestion).

```
<a href="http://bettercontactform.com" class="button-big" id="bcf_trigger" rel="bcf_trigger">Click</a>
```

Comment: Thanks but which function :(

Comment: In this example, `namedFunction` (though you should name it something better). As I said, you'll need to store a reference to it before-hand. With your example, it's an anonymous function that is immediately invoked - meaning you can't call it afterwards.

Comment: @ClaudiaFranchini I took a quick look at bettercontactform.com as that looks like what you're trying to implement and have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: i named it "showcontactform" but nothing changed... i really don't know what to do lol

Comment: Please see my edited answer, I checked the code that bettercontactform.com generates, and can see that you don't have the appropriate `href`, `id` and `rel` properties on your link.

Answer (score 0):

You should slightly modify your script and assign the function a name - e.g., "showContactForm":

```
function showContactForm() {
    var js, fjs = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    js = document.createElement("script");
    js.id = "bcf-render";
    js.src = "http://bettercontactform.com/contact/media/0/5/058aba0d4d2a6e62dff91304ae52fde4746db476.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}
```

And then call it the folllowing way - by adding it to an `onclick` handler:

```
<a href="#" class="button-big" onclick="showContactForm()">Click</a>
```

Comment: That's the problem i don't know which function to assign

Comment: @ClaudiaFranchini just copy and paste the code I've provided then :) You should replace your code in the `<script>` tag.

Comment: Thanks but this is didn't working because the function "Show contact form" isn't on the [link](http://bettercontactform.com/contact/media/0/5/058aba0d4d2a6e62dff91304ae52fde4746db476.js)